# What is the equivalent command to close for chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension what is the equivalent of close to chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage? I have tried:

```
window.close();
```

and

```
chrome.runtime.closeOptionsPage();
```

This would need to be invoked from within the options page itself.

**Update**

According to wOxxOm in the comments below, "window.close()" should work. So this may be a bug in my browser Edge.

wOxxOm suggested using "chrome.tabs.remove". However I get an error using it this way from within the options script:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
});

Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: window.close() is the correct method and it works inside the options page so if it didn't work for you it means your code was incorrect somehow.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's interesting. Yes, "window.close()" is not working for me. However the Edge extension page does not show any errors when I run my extension and click on the button to invoke the close command. So I don't know how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Might be a bug in Edge.

Comment: @wOxxOm from what I've read so far, that seems to be a likely explanation. Although I did read that "window.close" only works from the script (page?) that called the open, which is in contradiction to what you said.

Comment: That's in web scripts, but extension scripts aren't bound by that restriction. At least in Chrome extensions.

Comment: Annyway, you can just close the tab via chrome.tabs.remove API.

Comment: Judging by the error there can be two explanations: 1) you're runnng this code in a tab-less context such as the background page i.e. your code is incorrect or 2) Edge's implementation is seriously broken, but it's not surprising: the embedded extension options are known to be handled terribly by various browsers, each browser has its own set of super annoying quirks in that regard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226288/discussion-between-gornvix-and-woxxom).